# Can't echo a ajax .load function in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
$commentid = $row['comment_id'];
$commentidedit = "edit" . $commentid;

echo "$('#".$commentidedit."').load('editcomments.php')";
```

The .load function is somehow incorrect however I can't seem to find out why. Could anyone help me out with this? I didn't call the incorrect id because this code above is just a small part of of some code I have and if I dont include the code above, it runs just fine.

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: try to escape first `$` in quotes under echo statement

Comment: There is none because the php is correct (syntax) but the js I'm printing (that has the error) doesn't produce errors. This code above is supposed to be executed by a another button that I echoed out. (I know it doesn't work because I made sure that there is an alert when the button is clicked however there is none with this code. **in other words there is no error since its javascript**

Comment: @AnatoliyR what exactly do u mean by that?

Comment: @thespeciamone for `echo "some $text"` word `$text` will be echoed as value of variable `$text`, your quote is slightly different, but try to replace `$` with `\$` or use another solution to avoid single `$` in quotes

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @AnatoliyR I was stuck on this for such a long time!

Comment: Why . is used for concatination

Comment: @AnatoliyR Sorry, what I meant to say was that it does work but everytime I put it inside of my .click function, it breaks the code. However I found the solution! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone posted this in the comments:

`echo "\$('#".$commentidedit."').load('editcomments.php')";`

(added the \ in front of $)